# Jquery ui tabs:sortable weired element heights

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to create a simple ui tabs from basic structure.

I have four tabs

1. Apple
2. Orange
3. Mango
4. More

When I drag `Orange` and `More` their height increases and when dropped goes back to normal. This does not happen with `Apple` and `Mango` elements.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Apple</a> 
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-2">Orange</a> 
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-3">Mango</a> 
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-4">More</a> 
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation">Remove Tab</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"><p>Apple</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"><p>Orange</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"><p>Mango</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-4"><p>More</p></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #tabs li .ui-icon-close {
     float: left;
     margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
```

**JS** : [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/rKVqU/)

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
// Make Tabs Sortable
tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
    axis: "x",
    stop: function () {
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
    }
});
// close icon: removing the tab on click
tabs.delegate("span.ui-icon-close", "click", function () {
    var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
    $("#" + panelId).remove();
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
});
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS?

Comment: I have added css too but this is just to align close button.I think this close button css is the main problem.You can see my try at http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/rKVqU/

Comment: It only appears on the first 2 items. Its not depending on the text value of the Link. I'm trying to find whats different with the first 2.

Comment: Hi,

When dragging your Tabs the Javascript gives a fixed width to the li elements.
This width doesnt take the margin on the Close button into account.

Give your li a fixed width. Or include the margin off the close button in the calculation of the javascipt.

Comment: I think the problem is when sorting elements(for some elements), ```float:left;``` property of close is removed,which causes clsoes button to goto default position. But I dont know why some elements.

Comment: how can i do it in javascript ..

Comment: could you get a solution to this?

Comment: No till yet.Still looking to figure out.

Comment: OK, so I tweaked a bit, it is related to the css you put as  `#tabs li .ui-icon-close {`, try removing the right-margin from there and now **orange** and **more** work fine but other two start behaving bad.

Comment: @gaurav: You are right. I already tried that and this is driving me nuts. i also tried putting span inside <a> like ```<a><span></span></a>``` but doesnot work either

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I am suggesting is kind of a hack but as it is a pretty straight forward problem, not much is in our hands, the idea is to set **min-width** of the **li** elements inside **#tabs** greater than the current width up to around **3px**.

**Reason:** When someone tries to drag elements, the width of the **li** elements gets set by js which ultimately causes the UI distortion.

**Hack:** Use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tabs li').each(function(){
    var wd = (parseInt($(this).css('width').replace('px',''))+3)+'px';
    $(this).css('min-width',wd);
 });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gauravpandeyuit/rKVqU/12/)

Comment: Yeah but don't try to forget testing it in different browsers.. if something happens, try to increase the **min-width**

Comment: I still have to test this idea but may work.The idea is use ```<a><span></span></a>``` instead of using only ```<span></span>``` and then convert it to .button() using ui method.May be with button , this will not happen.

Comment: check this with button.http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/rKVqU/14/. seems to be working.Now just have to make button smaller.Is it working for you ?

Comment: yeah it worked for me too, but elements are fluctuation when being dragged, may be button size issue, not sure

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/rKVqU/15/ .. improved.
is this version fluctuating too for you? working fine for me. Firefox 24 + chrome 30

Answer (score 0):

**Posting Final code for someone who needs ..**

Changing to `<span>` to ui buttons works ..

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Apple</a> 
            <button>close</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-2">Orange</a> 
            <button>close</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-3">Mango</a> 
            <button>close</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-4">More</a> 
            <button>close</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"><p>Apple</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"><p>Orange</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"><p>Mango</p></div>
    <div id="tabs-4"><p>More</p></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { font-size: 62.5%; }

#tabs li button {
 margin-top:8%;
    margin-right:2px;
 font-size: 55%;

 }
```

**JS:**

```
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
// Make Tabs Sortable
tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
    axis: "x",
    stop: function () {
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
    }
});
// close icon: removing the tab on click
tabs.delegate("span.ui-icon-close", "click", function () {
    var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
    $("#" + panelId).remove();
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
});

$("button").button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-close"
    },
    text: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem, and I think this is the best fix.

- The problem here is that, when you hold and sort the li element, jquery ui adds its own 'sorting style' to the element. and when you place the li element in place, it reverts back to its original style.
- The sorting style rounds down the width css property, so if your width is 70.35px, it rounds it to 70px, any element or text is wrap to a new line because the width shrank.

Fix: when sorting starts, add an extra 1px width. When the sort ends, it will automatically revert back to the original width.
See example:

```
$(function() {
    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
      axis: "x",
      start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.width(ui.helper.width() + 1);
      }
    });
  });
```